# Create Repeated Fields in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(documnet).ready(function(){
$('#more_finance').click(function(){
                                var add_new ='<div class="form-group finance-contact" id="finance_3"><div class="col-sm-9"><label for="firstName" class="control-label">Finance Contact#</label></div><div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" id="finance" name="finance[]"placeholder="Finance Contact" class="form-control" autofocus></div>\n\
                                    <a href="#" class="delete_png"><img src="/img/deleted-box.png"></a></div>';
$(add_new).insertAfter( "#finance_1");
});
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group finance-contact" id="finance_1">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <label for="firstName" class="control-label">Finance Contact</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <input type="text" id="finance1" name="finance[]" placeholder="Finance Contact" class="form-control" autofocus>
                    </div>
            </div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
             <input type="button" id="more_finance" value="Add More">
            </div>
```

I want This Code insert multiple when click Add More Button And Also remove repeated fields

Comment: Where is you jQuery code?

Comment: i don't have jquery

Comment: i need jquery for this

Comment: We will not code this for you! We here to help with problems, and not doing your whole work ...

Comment: @eisbehr ok, i put my jquery here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Find Answer

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery('#more_senior').click(function(){
                                var finance_cont1=jQuery('.senior-contact').length; 
                                var finance_cont=finance_cont1+1;
                                var add_new ='<div class="form-group senior-contact" id="senior_'+finance_cont+'"><div class="col-sm-9"><label for="firstName" class="control-label">Senior Mgmt. Contact#</label></div><div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" id="seniormgmt'+finance_cont+'" name="seniormgmt[]"placeholder="Senior Mgmt. Contact" class="form-control" autofocus></div>\n\
                                <a href="#" class="delete_png">Remove</a></div>';
                                jQuery(add_new).insertAfter( "#senior_"+finance_cont1 );
                                delete_fields();
                            
                            });
  function delete_fields(){
                            $('.delete_png').on("click",function(){
                                    var class_name=jQuery(this).parent().attr('class');
                                    class_name=class_name.split(' ');
                                    var id_name=jQuery(this).parent().attr('id');
                                    var finance_cont2=jQuery('.'+class_name[1]).length; 
                                    var finance_cont3=finance_cont2-1;
                                    var id_first=id_name.split('_');
                                    $('#'+id_name).remove();
                                    delete_fields();
                        
                            });
                            }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4">
            <h4><strong>Senior Mgmt. Contacts</strong></h4>
            <div class="form-group senior-contact" id="senior_1">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <label for="firstName" class="control-label">Senior Mgmt. Contact</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <input type="text" id="seniormgmt1" value="" name="seniormgm[]" placeholder="Senior Mgmt. Contact" class="form-control" autofocus>
                    </div>
            </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
             <input type="button" id="more_senior" value="Add More">
            </div>
  </div>
```